# There is Error Message While Installing Golang Kafka Client (Confluent)

Tags: go, apache-kafka, confluent-platform

I want to ask about my problem in installing confluent golang kafka client on Mac OS Mojave.

Why is there always error message while installing golang kafka client `go get -u github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-go/kafka` even the `librdkafka` already installed?

The error message:

```
$GOPATH/src/github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-go/kafka/event.go:234:9: could not determine kind of name for C.RD_KAFKA_RESP_ERR__FATAL
$GOPATH/src/github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-go/kafka/event.go:242:18: could not determine kind of name for C.rd_kafka_fatal_error
```

The `librdkafka` is already installed `librdkafka 0.11.6 already installed`.

The `pkg-config` version already `0.29.2`.

What should i do to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like an issue with the confluent-kafka-go package on master branch.

If you use go modules and you bind the version to 0.11.6 it works.

go 1.12:

```sh
go get -u github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-go/kafka@v0.11.6
```

go 1.11:

```sh
GO111MODULE=on go get -u github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-go/kafka@v0.11.6
```

If you don't have go modules, clone the package under the correct go path and checkout to tag v0.11.6.

Comment: thanks, i clone the specific version that you state

Comment: Ok, if it works fine for you, please mark this answer as correct.